# Javascript php, autocomplete bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php

Sorry for my bad English, I don't understand javascript but I need a function. I try this code

```
<div class="well col-md-5">
   <input id="demo2" type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" placeholder="Search cities..." autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <pre class="prettyprint">
    </pre>
</div>
<script>

$(function() {

    function displayResult(item) {
        $('.alert').show().html('You selected <strong>' + item.value + '</strong>: <strong>' + item.text + '</strong>');
    }                    

    $('#demo2').typeahead({
        source: [
            {ID: 1, Name: 'Toronto'},
            {ID: 2, Name: 'Montreal'},
            {ID: 3, Name: 'New York'},
            {ID: 4, Name: 'Buffalo'},
            {ID: 5, Name: 'Boston'},
            {ID: 6, Name: 'Columbus'},
            {ID: 7, Name: 'Dallas'},
            {ID: 8, Name: 'Vancouver'},
            {ID: 9, Name: 'Seattle'},
            {ID: 10, Name: 'Los Angeles'}
        ],
        displayField: 'Name',
        valueField: 'ID',
        onSelect: displayResult
    });    

});
</script>
```

It works. But I have a file **clients.php** updated 2 times each day with this code

```
<?php
$client_listing ="
{ID: 1, Name: 'Toronto'},
{ID: 2, Name: 'Montreal'},
{ID: 3, Name: 'New York'},
{ID: 4, Name: 'Buffalo'},
{ID: 5, Name: 'Boston'},
{ID: 6, Name: 'Columbus'},
{ID: 7, Name: 'Dallas'},
{ID: 8, Name: 'Vancouver'},
{ID: 9, Name: 'Seattle'},
{ID: 10, Name: 'Los Angeles'}";
?>
```

I try to replace `$client_listing` to my first code but it doesn't work

```
<?php include('data/clients.php'); ?>
<script>

$(function() {

    function displayResult(item) {
        $('.alert').show().html('You selected <strong>' + item.value + '</strong>: <strong>' + item.text + '</strong>');
    }                    

    $('#demo2').typeahead({
        source: [
            <?php echo $client_listing; ?>
        ],
        displayField: 'Name',
        valueField: 'ID',
        onSelect: displayResult
    });    

});
</script>
```

Thank you for the help

Didier

Answer (score 1):

You should try with:

```
<?php 
 $client_listing ='
{"ID": 1, "Name": "Toronto"},
{"ID": 2, "Name": "Montreal"},
{"ID": 3, "Name": "New York"},
{"ID": 4, "Name": "Buffalo'},
{"ID": 5, "Name": "Boston"},
{"ID": 6, "Name": "Columbus"},
{"ID": 7, "Name": "Dallas"},
{"ID": 8, "Name": "Vancouver"},
{"ID": 9, "Name": "Seattle"},
{"ID": 10, "Name": "Los Angeles"}';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in data/clients.php

```
<?php
function getClients()
{
    $clients = array(
        array('ID' => 1, 'Name' => 'Toronto'),
        array('ID' => 2, 'Name' => 'Montreal'),
        array('ID' => 3, 'Name' => 'New York'),
        array('ID' => 4, 'Name' => 'Buffalo'),
        array('ID' => 5, 'Name' => 'Boston'),
        array('ID' => 6, 'Name' => 'Columbus'),
        array('ID' => 7, 'Name' => 'Dallas'),
        array('ID' => 8, 'Name' => 'Vancouver'),
        array('ID' => 9, 'Name' => 'Seattle'),
        array('ID' => 10, 'Name' => 'Los Angeles')
    );

    return json_encode($clients);
}
// no end php tag
```

In your js section

```
$('#demo2').typeahead({
    source: <?php echo getClients(); ?>,
    displayField: 'Name',
    valueField: 'ID',
    onSelect: displayResult
});
```